# How to replace the Key for sort field in a meteor collection query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In the code below, I want to replace the name key with a value being passed in via a parameter `this.params.sortby` but I can't get it working. Looking for some help.

So if:

```
this.params.sortby=location
```

I want this:

```
Template.MyTemplate.helpers({
    data: function () {
      return MyCollection.find({},{sort:{name: 1 }});
    }
  });
```

To become this:

```
Template.MyTemplate.helpers({
    data: function () {
      return MyCollection.find({},{sort:{location: 1 }});
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an object with the bracket notation to achieve dynamic key naming, like this :

```
var sorter={};
sorter[this.params.sortby]=1;
```

Assuming that `this.params.sortby` is equal to the `String` "age", you'd have the following `sorter` object :

```
var sorter={
  age:1
};
```

Then you can use to sort your collection appropriately :

```
MyCollection.find({},{sort:sorter});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a SORT factory builder to generate sort criteria before query.